# Jquery Mobile Anchors doesn't link.

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This #dialogPage_27 doesnt work. I really need help because many people cant help me giving the answer. The Anchor ##dialogPage_27 is in the same file so I dont get why it doesn't work.

core.php

```
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
  <div data-role="header">
    <a href="../maingenres.php" data-icon="back"></a>
    <h3>Core Genres</h3>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div id="ball-three2" class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#dialogPage_27" data-transition="slidedown" data-rel="dialog">
          <h3>Noise<br/>core</h3>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="dialogPage_27"  data-transition="slidedown" data-rel="dialog">
  <h1 class="verplaatsing">Noisecore</h1>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content"> 
    <?php
      getData("noisecore");
          ?>
  </div>
  <?php
    getMore("noisecore");
        ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a dialog, instead of data-rel="dialog", try data-dialog="true" on the dialog page: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages-dialog/

```
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
  <div data-role="header">
    <a href="../maingenres.php" data-icon="back"></a>
    <h3>Core Genres</h3>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div id="ball-three2" class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#dialogPage_27" data-transition="slidedown" >
          <h3>Noise<br/>core</h3>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="dialogPage_27"  data-dialog="true">
  <h1 class="verplaatsing">Noisecore</h1>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content"> 
     dialog content
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fw86a8z0/)**

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't open the dialog.

Comment: He doesn't open views/core.php#dialogPage_27. If I click on the anchor.

Comment: @user3360104, did you run the demo jsFiddle I linked? It opend the dialog. Perhaps you can post the entire html of your page including script references, css links, meta tags etc.

Comment: that is so much code. because i split the homepage and made seperate pages to load the stuff other wise jquery mobile loads whole source and images at once.